# Unable to create Area in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working with a project where I am using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. I am trying to **add new scaffolded item** which is an MVC Area.
But I keep getting an error.

- Here is link to GitHub for this project: [click](https://github.com/SheikhMdAbdullah1/Bulk.git)

Here are 2 relevant screenshots:

[image]

[image]

**How can I solve this problem?**

**Note:** this may be an important factor for this problem:

```
Error NU1202 Package System.Threading 4.3.0 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package System.Threading 4.3.0 supports: monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
```

Comment: Which command you use in your `Package Manager  Console` ? I have downloaded your project and can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Could you tell me how to reproduce it?

Answer (score 3):

After downloaded your project. I add this line

```
.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

in `Program.cs` file. And I also install the Packages like yours , and It works fine.

#### My test steps

1. Delete `.vs`, `bin`, `obj` folder.
2. Open the project
3. Install the packages

   [image]
4. Run the app, and works fine

#### Suggestion

1. Delete the 3 folder mentioned above.
2. Upgrade your vs2022 to the lastest version

Comment: I cannot do this man. .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation() cannot be added. Is there any packages I need to install.

Comment: @Shuvo Can your program run normally locally?

Comment: @Shuvo I added the package because I had an error message when I was running it locally.

Comment: Bro, I am really suffering with this. Can you download the project and do as you instructed and give me that through GitHub?

Comment: Bro I did as you suggested. But Some of the packages is not installing. The error in the package that I showed in the question is coming. The version 4.3.0 of system.threading in not installing.

Comment: Which package is that visualstudio.web.codegenerator.......... Can't see that in the image.

Answer (score 1):

just need remove or comment

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

in your program.cs file and try again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).